# Tile error and Parameter 'left' is required. in subtract function of Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am getting an error trying to subtract one property from another in GEE:

```
Tile error: Error in map(ID=null):
Number.subtract: Parameter 'left' is required.
```

here is my code:

```
var urb=ee.FeatureCollection('users/data');

//print(urb);


// This function computes the feature's UHI
var getUHI = function(feature) {
//  print(ee.Number.parse(feature.get('LST_urb_day_CT')));
  var urban = ee.Number(feature.get('LST_urb_day_CT'));
  var UHI = urban.subtract(ee.Number(feature.getNumber('LST_rur_day')));
  return feature.set({UHI: UHI});
};

// Map the area getting function over the FeatureCollection.
var UHIAdded = urb.map(getUHI);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a method of an Earth Engine value/object, the type of the value has to be known when *your code is executed*, which happens before the request is even sent to Earth Engine's servers.

You know the property's value is a number. The Earth Engine server will find out it a number. But the Earth Engine client library that's processing `feature.get(...)` doesn't know that, so you have to tell it that the value will be a number:

```
var urban = ee.Number(feature.get('LST_urb_day_CT'));
```

In most cases, this is automatic because the type is implied by the method/algorithm you used — for example, `urb.map` knows that `feature` is a feature because `urb` is a FeatureCollection. But the values of properties are always of unknown type since they could be almost anything, so you usually need a cast along with `.get()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed your commet but it is now giving me this error... somehow the number didn't match with the FeatureCollection? census track: Tile error: Error in map(ID=null):
Number.subtract: Parameter 'left' is required.

Comment: @GaoleDai That means the property is missing on that feature.

Comment: I tried to drop Nulls by replacing it with var UHIAdded = urb.map(getUHI, true); but it still says the same error?

Comment: @GaoleDai dropNulls doesn't have any effect there because it applies to the result of the map(), by which time the error has already occurred. Try using `.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['LST_urb_day_CT']))` before the `.map()`.